# g++ won't work on Lion

Tags: macos, compilation, g++, osx-lion

I have searched and I have received the same answer but I believe mine is different
I have Xcode (4.3.2) installed on my mac and when I try to compile my .cpp file it says "command not found" Any suggestions?

How I try to compile;
`g++ -o program code.cpp`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install the "Command-Line Tools" package through the XCode "Downloads" preferences tab.

Comment: I've been pounding my head against the wall to find out why I could not get g++ or gcc to work.  Thank you for this answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

open Xcode >> Preferences... >> Downloads and download command line tools

Answer (score -3):

I use

```
make code
```

and it finds a compiler, compiles code.cpp and leaves the output in code.  And it tells me the name of the compiler...  (it is g++).

If you type "which g++" do you find an old alias?

Do you have /usr/bin in your path?

If you do, and /usr/bin/g++ isn't found, check that you've downloaded not only Xcode but the command line utilities that are now a separate download on the developer page.

Comment: can you show me how can I apply for this specific situation like 'make code code.cpp' or something else?

Comment: If you have a file by the name code.cpp and you have the command line utilities installed, typing
    make code
invokes g++ -o code code.cpp